# How do I use a TabHost in a Dialog?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost, android-dialog

I see plenty of `Dialog`s inside a `TabHost` but not the other way around. So how can I use a `TabHost` layout inside of a `Dialog`. I also don't want to have to use `Intent`s for each `Tab` if its possible because it just seems messy for what I want to do.

Basically I want to launch a `Dialog` that I use for a menu and I would like to have a `TabHost` to navigate through all the menu choices. There's a lot of them :) Right now I just set the XML layout to a `Dialog` but I'm confused on how to set up a `TabHost` inside that dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I made a `HostTab` layout and named each Linear/Relative layout and declared each tab I created to use the Linear/Relative layout from the XML file where they were declared like so:

```
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.maintabmenu);
 TabHost tabs = (TabHost) dialog.findViewById(R.id.my_tabhost);
 tabs.setup();
 tabs.setCurrentTab(0);

 TabSpec tspec11 = tabs.newTabSpec("Tab1");
 tspec11.setIndicator("NEWTAB");

 tspec11.setContent(R.id.ScrollView01);
 tabs.addTab(tspec11);

 TabSpec tspec2 = tabs.newTabSpec("Tab2");
 tspec2.setIndicator("NEWTAB");

 tspec2.setContent(R.id.ScrollView02);
 tabs.addTab(tspec2);
```

I still have all the buttons and other views with each of the inner layouts declared so everything works just like I wanted :) yay for me lol

But thanks to *@R.daneel.oliva* for trying to jump in :)

Comment: Thank you for this you saved me a lot of time.  Now I don't have to create 5 activity's and XML files.

Comment: Unfortunately I no longer have access to the project files from that source but the way it was structured was that I essentially took layouts that would traditionally be in different files and placed them into one big file that way they were all inflated already when I set the content view.

Answer (score 2):

I will like to point out an other approach,

Instead of making a complicated dialog that is difficult to maintain and maybe even use why not open a separate activity in the dialog mode by using the following code in the activity tag in the manifest file

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

This way you can hve all the complexities & capabilities of an activity in a dialog.

I hope it helps..

Comment: But by making a new activity to just launch a menu seems a lot more complicated and complex than just having a simple dialog with a tabhost set up in it. I dont need a seperate activity to run a simple menu.....that just seems really overkill. Im working on getting it how I want I just have a weird nullpointer for some reason at one line in my code.

Comment: OK, Can you post some code & mention where the code throws an exception and what kind of exception.

Comment: Hey thanks for helping but I just figured it out....I wasnt calling  tabs.setup(); and then further down in my code I had a Textview that I wasnt using anymore that was causing the error. It didnt show itself until I realized I wasnt using tabs.setup(); .